# Openwebload installation linux

Tags: linux, debian

Am trying to install openwebload in Debian. I realize the latest version is pretty old. I used alien to convert the rpm to deb. When trying to run openload as a command however I get this error:

```
openload: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So what I did was to have the current libstdc++ version 6.0 act as the basis for my symbolic link (6.2-2) . That works okay but I encounter this other problem which has been perplexing me.

```
  undefined symbol: __builtin_vec_new
```

I do realize this has to do with old library, but I can't find a more recent version of openload.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-2.95/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb .

Found the link on this site http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1517863&page=2